# Remove items from list of dicts with a matching attribute

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts for instance:

```
data = [
    { 'id': 1 },
    { 'id': 2 },
    { 'id': 3 },
    { 'id': 4 },
    { 'id': 5 },
]

remove_ids = [3,4]
```

So I'd like to apply `remove_ids` to `list` and end up with only:

```
list = [
    { 'id': 1 },
    { 'id': 2 },
    { 'id': 5 },
]
```

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
data.remove([item (if item['id'] in remove_ids) for k, item in data])
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but I'm interested to know whether I was even close. I was also interested to see if this is even possibly in a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = [d for d in data if d['id'] not in remove_ids]
```

Comment: The winner by 1 second! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
new_data=[x for x in data if x['id'] not in remove_ids]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `filter`.

```
remove_ids = (3, 4)
filtered_data = filter(lambda item: item['id'] not in remove_ids, data)
```

If `data` is large or you do this very frequently, you might also get benefit out of `itertools`.

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse
remove_ids = (3, 4)
filtered_data = tuple(ifilterfalse(lambda item: item['id'] in remove_ids, data))
```

Comment: Interesting. I really need to get my head around lambda, it still mangles my brain.

Comment: Note that straight list comprehensions and generators are generally considered more Pythonic though.